# JSON Date coming through as Today's date?

Tags: javascript, json, date

I'm trying to convert a JSON date to a dd/mm/yyyy format, which I'm managing to do semi-successfully.

The problem I'm encountering is that the date from the record in the DB is for example, 2009-06-29 which is returning the usual JSON `/Date(1246230000000)/`, however, when I try and turn it into the previously mention dd/mm/yyyy format, it's coming through as today's date.

The code I'm using to try and do this is:

```
$('input#EmployeeName').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    $('#StartDate').html(formatJSONDate(Date(!data ? '' : data.StartDate)));
});

function formatJSONDate(jsonDate) {
    var newDate = dateFormat(jsonDate, "dd/mm/yyyy");
    return newDate;
}
```

I'm using [JavaScript Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) to try and run the function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what the actual JSON looks like? Because JSON doesn't **have** a date type (see http://json.org/), the `/Date(xxxx)/` thing is just convention some people use. If we can see what actually shows up in your JSON, we can help you convert it.

Comment: Not clear where that 1224043200000 number is coming from; it's neither seconds nor milliseconds since The Epoch for 1999-12-31 (which is 946598400000).

Comment: The date itself and the JSON are just examples. I'll edit the original question to use accurate info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your JSON looks something like this:

```
{
    "StartDate": "/Date(1224043200000)/"
}
```

you can convert it into an actual Javascript date like so:

```
var dt, millis;

millis = data.StartDate.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);
if (millis) {
    dt = new Date(Number(millis[1]));
}
```

That extracts the milliseconds since The Epoch value from the string and uses it to create a Date instance.

Comment: And then you can `alert(dt.getDate()+'/'+(dt.getMonth()+1)+'/'+dt.getFullYear())`